# The equality $r(A)=\omega(A)=\|A\|$ is not true in general.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, examples-counterexamples

Let $\mathcal{B}(F)$ the algebra of all bounded linear operators on a complex Hilbert space $F$.

It is well know that if $A$ is **hyponormal operator**, then 
$$r(A)=\omega(A)=\|A\|,$$
where $r(A)$, $\omega(A)$ and $\|A\|$ denote respectively the spectral radius, the numerical radius and the norm of $A$.

> I want to find an example of an operator $A$ such that the equality
>   $$r(A)=\omega(A)=\|A\|,$$
>   does not hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ on the Hilbert space $\mathbb{C}^2$ with the Euclidean inner product has

$$r(A)=1 \\
\omega(A)=\max_{|x|^2+|y|^2=1} |x|^2+y\overline{x}+|y|^2=3/2 \\
\| A \|=\max_{|x|^2+|y|^2=1} \sqrt{|x+y|^2+|y|^2}=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}.$$

Note that regardless of any assumption you have $r(A) \leq \omega(A) \leq \| A \|$, and this example shows that both inequalities can simultaneously be strict.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Here $F$ is a complex Hilbert sapce. So we have $$\omega(A)=\max_{|x|^2+|y|^2=1} |x|^2+y\bar{x}+|y|^2.$$

Comment: @Schüler Thanks, that's a straightforward fix.

Comment: Please I'm facing difficulties to prove that $$\| A \|=\max_{|x|^2+|y|^2=1} \sqrt{|x+y|^2+|y|^2}=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}.$$ Thank you for your help.

Comment: I try with the following theorem; Let $T\in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$
$$\|T\|=\max\{\sqrt{\lambda};\;\lambda\in \sigma(T^*T)\}=\max\{\sqrt{\lambda};\;\lambda\in\sigma(TT^*)\}.$$ However I find $$\|A\|^2=\frac{3+\sqrt5}{2}$$ Where is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Nothing, it is just that $\| A \|^2=\| A\| +1$ in this situation.

Comment: But please we have
$$\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}+3}{2}\right)^{1/2}\neq \frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}.$$
Please where is my mistake? Thanks.

Comment: No, those two definitely are equal, check it.